# How do I make ToolkitScriptManager get a newer version of AJAX scripts?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, toolkitscriptmanager

I'm trying to upgrade the version of AjaxControlToolkit that we're using in a ASP.NET 3.5 project. It builds fine but when I load a page with an AjaxControlToolkit control on it gives the error:

> JavaScript runtime error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced. If you are using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in AjaxControlToolkit.dll.

We are using a class that extends ToolkitScriptManager with a reference to AjaxControlToolkit as our ScriptManager.

Having looked at the javascript, I can tell that the version that's being included does not contain some of the updates that the .js source files included in the toolkit download have. I'm not sure where the ToolkitScriptManager is getting its AJAX .js files from but I need to find a way to force it to use the newer versions.

Simply including them as embedded resources in the project has not worked.

I am building this project in VS2008 3.5 SP1 (as required by client). I am trying to build AjaxControlToolkit from the source code, as there are a few extensions which we need to apply to the Toolkit controls.

I would be happy to provide further details if they're helpful.

EDIT: As it turns out, I had commented out the line `ApplyAssembly(e.Script, false);` in my copy of ToolkitScriptManager. Putting it back in caused the execution to instead fail in `GetBaseUrl` with an `InvalidOperationException`:

> Assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' does not contain a Web resource with name 'MicrosoftAjax.js'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran into this problem on a new project I started yesterday. In the solution explorer, right click on your project. Navigate to Manage NuGet Packages.. in the search box, type AjaxControlToolkit. Install it and this should fix your problems! If you need NuGet then go to  http://www.nuget.org/ and install the package. I hope this helps!

Comment: I'm not using NuGet - I've downloaded the AjaxControlToolkit source code from CodePlex and I'm trying to compile it.

Comment: @fortyCakes Yes. I have had issues with the referencing of the .dll from the zip. I'm not sure why but if you look at their site, they do tell you to use NuGet. I would try installing it through NuGet as it did solve my problem and it was very similar to yours. I have used NuGet to get a lot of different packages and libraries and it did fix my problem. Even if it doesn't fix yours, NuGet will still become valuable to you in the future. This is the link from the codeplex website.. http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c

Comment: Thanks, I got the latest version to an empty project and compared them - the AssemblyInfo.cs I had was wrong.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use the NuGet version in the actual product as we need to be able to view and change the source code.